# How to get all matching data in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having two arrays, One is `departments` and another is `jobtitles`

```js
const departments = [
  {
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "SectorID": 5,
    "Name": "Production",
    "SortOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "DepartmentID": 52,
    "SectorID": 5,
    "Name": "Design/Engineering",
    "SortOrder": 2
  },
  {
    "DepartmentID": 92,
    "SectorID": 5,
    "Name": "Consulting",
    "SortOrder": 8
  },
  {
    "DepartmentID": 114,
    "SectorID": 24,
    "Name": "Administration",
    "SortOrder": 5
  }
]

const jobTitles = [
  {
    "JobTitleID": 167,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Production Manager",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 5
  },
    {
    "JobTitleID": 294,
    "DepartmentID": 52,
    "JobName": "Senior Truss Designer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 5
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 178,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Production Supervisor",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 3
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 191,
    "DepartmentID": 92,
    "JobName": "Saw Shop Supervisor",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 461,
    "DepartmentID": 114,
    "JobName": "Sawyer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 7
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 461,
    "DepartmentID": 66,
    "JobName": "Sawyer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 7
   },
    {
    "JobTitleID": 474,
    "DepartmentID": 92,
    "JobName": "Senior Truss Designer - Part Time",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 11
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 449,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Senior Wall Panel Designer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 15
  },
 {
    "JobTitleID": 278,
    "DepartmentID": 114,
    "JobName": "Service Manager",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 2
 }
]

const filteredData = departments.map(department => {
  return jobTitles.find(jobTitle => jobTitle.DepartmentID === department.DepartmentID)
})

console.log('filteredData ', filteredData)
```

Here I need to get all the matching records of `DepartmentId` in both departments and jobtitles array.

So I have tried like,

```
const filteredData = departments.map(department => {
  return jobTitles.find(jobTitle => jobTitle.DepartmentID === department.DepartmentID)
})
```

But this results in only first matching record like,

**Current Output:**

```
[
  {
    "JobTitleID": 167,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Production Manager",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 5
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 294,
    "DepartmentID": 52,
    "JobName": "Senior Truss Designer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 5
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 191,
    "DepartmentID": 92,
    "JobName": "Saw Shop Supervisor",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 461,
    "DepartmentID": 114,
    "JobName": "Sawyer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 7
  }
]
```

But I need to get all matching records for the particular `DepartmentId`.

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {
    "JobTitleID": 167,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Production Manager",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 5
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 178,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Production Supervisor",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 3
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 449,
    "DepartmentID": 51,
    "JobName": "Senior Wall Panel Designer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 15
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 294,
    "DepartmentID": 52,
    "JobName": "Senior Truss Designer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 5
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 191,
    "DepartmentID": 92,
    "JobName": "Saw Shop Supervisor",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 1
  },
  {
    "JobTitleID": 461,
    "DepartmentID": 114,
    "JobName": "Sawyer",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 7
  },
 {
    "JobTitleID": 278,
    "DepartmentID": 114,
    "JobName": "Service Manager",
    "Deleted": false,
    "SortOrder": 2
 }
]
```

Eg.., `DepartmentID` **51** has three matching records but it displays only one record.

Kindly help me to get all related matching records when the departments `DepartmentId` is equal to jobTitles `DepartmentId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `filter` instead of `find` and `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```js
const departments = [{"DepartmentID":51,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Production","SortOrder":1},{"DepartmentID":52,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Design/Engineering","SortOrder":2},{"DepartmentID":92,"SectorID":5,"Name":"Consulting","SortOrder":8},{"DepartmentID":114,"SectorID":24,"Name":"Administration","SortOrder":5}]

const jobTitles = [{"JobTitleID":167,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Production Manager","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":5},{"JobTitleID":294,"DepartmentID":52,"JobName":"Senior Truss Designer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":5},{"JobTitleID":178,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Production Supervisor","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":3},{"JobTitleID":191,"DepartmentID":92,"JobName":"Saw Shop Supervisor","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":1},{"JobTitleID":461,"DepartmentID":114,"JobName":"Sawyer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":7},{"JobTitleID":461,"DepartmentID":66,"JobName":"Sawyer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":7},{"JobTitleID":474,"DepartmentID":92,"JobName":"Senior Truss Designer - Part Time","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":11},{"JobTitleID":449,"DepartmentID":51,"JobName":"Senior Wall Panel Designer","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":15},{"JobTitleID":278,"DepartmentID":114,"JobName":"Service Manager","Deleted":false,"SortOrder":2}]

const filteredData = departments.flatMap(department => {
  return jobTitles.filter(jobTitle => jobTitle.DepartmentID === department.DepartmentID)
})

console.log('filteredData ', filteredData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array with same `departmentsID`.

Then sort by `departmentsID` and `JobTitleID`.

```js
const
    departments = [{ DepartmentID: 51, SectorID: 5, Name: "Production", SortOrder: 1 }, { DepartmentID: 52, SectorID: 5, Name: "Design/Engineering", SortOrder: 2 }, { DepartmentID: 92, SectorID: 5, Name: "Consulting", SortOrder: 8 }, { DepartmentID: 114, SectorID: 24, Name: "Administration", SortOrder: 5 }],
    jobTitles = [{ JobTitleID: 167, DepartmentID: 51, JobName: "Production Manager", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 5 }, { JobTitleID: 294, DepartmentID: 52, JobName: "Senior Truss Designer", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 5 }, { JobTitleID: 178, DepartmentID: 51, JobName: "Production Supervisor", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 3 }, { JobTitleID: 191, DepartmentID: 92, JobName: "Saw Shop Supervisor", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 1 }, { JobTitleID: 461, DepartmentID: 114, JobName: "Sawyer", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 7 }, { JobTitleID: 461, DepartmentID: 66, JobName: "Sawyer", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 7 }, { JobTitleID: 474, DepartmentID: 92, JobName: "Senior Truss Designer - Part Time", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 11 }, { JobTitleID: 449, DepartmentID: 51, JobName: "Senior Wall Panel Designer", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 15 }, { JobTitleID: 278, DepartmentID: 114, JobName: "Service Manager", Deleted: false, SortOrder: 2 }],
    departmentsIDs = new Set(departments.map(({ departmentsID }) => departmentsID)),
    filteredData = jobTitles
        .filter(({ departmentsID }) => departmentsIDs.has(departmentsID))
        .sort((a, b) =>
            a.departmentsID - b.departmentsID ||
            a.JobTitleID - b.JobTitleID
        );

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```